# Zip isn't emitting values after the first values from both observables have been emitted

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to combine two observables, one of em being route params and the other one a custom one.

I'm using `zip` because `forkJoin` doesn't seem to work. But the zip is acting strange, cuz when I emit my custom one I don't get that value. I only get the first null value which has been given to my `BehaviorSubject` as a default emit value.

I read this

> "The zip operator will subscribe to all inner observables, waiting for
>   each to emit a value. Once this occurs, all values with the
>   corresponding index will be emitted. This will continue until at least
>   one inner observable completes."

Does that mean that it won't respond until both of the observables emit a value? Because the route params observable will only emit once, but the `dataEmitter` will continue to emit values. What would be the correct operator to use in this case?

Here's some of my code:

Emitter in my service:

```
private dataEmitter: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

Component subscription, only get `null` from the `dataEmitter`, never `this.calculatedData`:

```
Observable.zip(this.route.params, this.dataCalculator.dataEmitter$)
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

This is called when all of the calculations have been done:

```
this.dataEmitter.next(this.calculatedData);
```

Comment: Yes, `zip` behaves as described in the quote in your question. It sounds like you are looking for [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest).

Comment: @cartant Yes that does seem to do the trick. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @cartant switching to `combineLatest` works as expected:

```
Observable.combineLatest(this.route.params, this.dataCalculator.dataEmitter$)
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your zip works just fine. `null` is a value. You could use `dataEmitter.filter(val => !isNullOrUndefined(val))` to filter the null and undefined values.